# Prevent to Git Hook `post-commit` execute for submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks, git-commit

Can I somehow prevent that the `post-commit` hook being called when I commit something in the submodule? I'm using this hook to automatically commit the submodule changes with the main project commit message and I'm getting in a "infinity loop".

File: `post-commit`

```
#!/bin/sh
if git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    echo no submodule changes
else
    git submodule foreach git add . ;
    git submodule foreach git commit -am "`cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`"
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: just FYI, the reused commit message part could be done via `-F <file>` or `-c <commit> --reset-author` besides `-m <message>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to fix properly but running the command for each submodule I didn't face this problem anymore:

```
git submodule foreach "git diff-index --quiet HEAD -- || (git add . ; git commit -am \"`cat .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`\" || :)"
```